# Not able to deploy contract on a local Substrate node

Tags: deployment, smartcontracts, substrate, polkadot

`enter code here`I am referring following URL related to Substrate Developer Hub
https://substrate.dev/substrate-contracts-workshop/#/0/introduction
I have made up to following steps:

- Setup
- Creating an ink! Project
- Building Your Contract
- Running a Substrate Node at 9944

After successfully installing substrate, you can start a local development chain by running:
$ `substrate --dev`
But I am not able to do the step: Deploying our contract on a local Substrate node
When I am clicking on Deploy button nothing happens, just shows 33% of block time

substrate 2.0.0-rc4-00768a1f2-x86_64-linux-gnu

api v1.32.0-beta.24

apps v0.57.0-beta.34

[image: deploy contract on a local Substrate node]

Substrate Node:

```
azhar@hamza:~$ cd substrate
azhar@hamza:~/substrate$ cd flipper/
azhar@hamza:~/substrate/flipper$ 
azhar@hamza:~/substrate/flipper$ ls -lrt
total 32
-rwxr-xr-x 1 azhar azhar  2485 Sep  6 15:35 lib.rs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 azhar azhar  1841 Sep  6 15:35 Cargo.toml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 azhar azhar 17773 Sep  6 15:40 Cargo.lock
drwxrwxr-x 6 azhar azhar  4096 Sep  6 15:59 target

azhar@hamza:~/substrate/flipper$ substrate purge-chain --dev -y
"/home/azhar/.local/share/substrate/chains/dev/db" removed.

azhar@hamza:~/substrate/flipper$ substrate --dev
2020-09-07 07:39:08 Running in --dev mode, RPC CORS has been disabled.
2020-09-07 07:39:08 Substrate Node
2020-09-07 07:39:08 ✌️  version 2.0.0-rc4-00768a1f2-x86_64-linux-gnu
2020-09-07 07:39:08 ❤️  by Parity Technologies <admin@parity.io>, 2017-2020
2020-09-07 07:39:08  Chain specification: Development
2020-09-07 07:39:08   Node name: cuddly-drink-4879
2020-09-07 07:39:08  Role: AUTHORITY
2020-09-07 07:39:08  Database: RocksDb at /home/azhar/.local/share/substrate/chains/dev/db
2020-09-07 07:39:08 ⛓  Native runtime: node-254 (substrate-node-0.tx1.au10)
2020-09-07 07:39:09  Highest known block at #5
2020-09-07 07:39:09 Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs
2020-09-07 07:39:09   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWHSShfTJguampmVq7bQ6ND66MCi58fpJcDJ1AbRZM2dic (legacy representation: QmWErSvST4ShC1rw8v9fJbbCTbG4F7eppTd95NeAWY9UMf)
2020-09-07 07:39:09 〽 Prometheus server started at 127.0.0.1:9615
2020-09-07 07:39:09  Starting BABE Authorship worker
2020-09-07 07:39:12  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0xe648d7b44aee8d408fdfb38a1a512397938da9041267ff021d08cb2a11ad31e8
2020-09-07 07:39:12 Timeout fired waiting for transaction pool at block #5. Proceeding with production.
2020-09-07 07:39:12  Prepared block for proposing at 6 [hash: 0x4f2ac0073a62c094d81aa89a6b4e4713946ece49a8a8a906cc5ac32b9b5ad6e6; parent_hash: 0xe648…31e8; extrinsics (2): [0x903e…9c56, 0xffb8…6c71]]
2020-09-07 07:39:12  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 6. Hash now 0xcb5bcb8d622e93f95deeb0822ed0500d74422793b38bfaa1c7cf7a4799d3db21, previously 0x4f2ac0073a62c094d81aa89a6b4e4713946ece49a8a8a906cc5ac32b9b5ad6e6.
2020-09-07 07:39:12 ✨ Imported #6 (0xcb5b…db21)
2020-09-07 07:39:14  Idle (0 peers), best: #6 (0xcb5b…db21), finalized #3 (0xd057…dfe0), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2020-09-07 07:39:15  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0xcb5bcb8d622e93f95deeb0822ed0500d74422793b38bfaa1c7cf7a4799d3db21
2020-09-07 07:39:15  Prepared block for proposing at 7 [hash: 0x85c9eadf126bf0daba6982110fd8ef2f13b661e8247c3808c6658b861be20c3e; parent_hash: 0xcb5b…db21; extrinsics (2): [0xbe45…4887, 0xa39a…6960]]
2020-09-07 07:39:15  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 7. Hash now 0x31f0f64913af4b02d98719f96f37c5a82f6ab404e1f96dc91e56cf8f8f27f6b8, previously 0x85c9eadf126bf0daba6982110fd8ef2f13b661e8247c3808c6658b861be20c3e.
2020-09-07 07:39:15 ✨ Imported #7 (0x31f0…f6b8)
2020-09-07 07:39:18  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x31f0f64913af4b02d98719f96f37c5a82f6ab404e1f96dc91e56cf8f8f27f6b8
2020-09-07 07:39:18  Prepared block for proposing at 8 [hash: 0x4a057e104d63d7784def003d43da9b3e333bf5f5b69be4fc6954418e19ace82a; parent_hash: 0x31f0…f6b8; extrinsics (2): [0xd616…0462, 0xc5b9…e350]]
2020-09-07 07:39:18  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 8. Hash now 0x026ddb720761397a34049e19be8d2e185e794f393e5e1986b5d65b1468cb81cb, previously 0x4a057e104d63d7784def003d43da9b3e333bf5f5b69be4fc6954418e19ace82a.
2020-09-07 07:39:18 ✨ Imported #8 (0x026d…81cb)
2020-09-07 07:39:19  Idle (0 peers), best: #8 (0x026d…81cb), finalized #5 (0xe648…31e8), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2020-09-07 07:39:21  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x026ddb720761397a34049e19be8d2e185e794f393e5e1986b5d65b1468cb81cb
2020-09-07 07:39:21  Prepared block for proposing at 9 [hash: 0x8d58e9c865aabbb5b8c3eec80d15a106d39bfe89ec864ccf18c21b1fef9abc8e; parent_hash: 0x026d…81cb; extrinsics (2): [0xc215…0183, 0xde49…95b5]]
2020-09-07 07:39:21  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 9. Hash now 0x81c49824c699aa35d7c1b2a3865d4ade61e6b0a7296f4863f106ba9da2ddd19c, previously 0x8d58e9c865aabbb5b8c3eec80d15a106d39bfe89ec864ccf18c21b1fef9abc8e.
2020-09-07 07:39:21 ✨ Imported #9 (0x81c4…d19c)
2020-09-07 07:39:24  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x81c49824c699aa35d7c1b2a3865d4ade61e6b0a7296f4863f106ba9da2ddd19c
2020-09-07 07:39:24  Idle (0 peers), best: #9 (0x81c4…d19c), finalized #7 (0x31f0…f6b8), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2020-09-07 07:39:24  Prepared block for proposing at 10 [hash: 0x588cbe09dd30583aacc367076142d54fccd9347d6572335e19dce577dfb07283; parent_hash: 0x81c4…d19c; extrinsics (2): [0x0267…282d, 0x22af…666b]]
2020-09-07 07:39:24  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 10. Hash now 0x9f25dc3a8c5d67d8b944ca51416945ae6df6300431eb9b196866d7a9580b5db3, previously 0x588cbe09dd30583aacc367076142d54fccd9347d6572335e19dce577dfb07283.
2020-09-07 07:39:24 ✨ Imported #10 (0x9f25…5db3)
```

Any Idea? All assistance are appreciated

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you are seeing? What does your node terminal say?

Comment: Thanks for prompt response!, I have attached screen shot and Substrate Node terminal output also.

Comment: The 33% of block time message is not indicative of anything deploying. It is a response to the maximum gas allowed param. What happens when you click deploy?

Comment: When I click on "Deploy" button, Nothing happens! Screen remains as it is! I can click any number times.No change.

Comment: I would recommend purging chain `substrate purge-chain --dev -y` and trying again. You have not yet provided any errors or hints as to what the issue might be. You can also look in your browser console to see if there are any errors when clicking the deploy button.

Comment: As suggested I have done substrate purge-chain --dev -y which I have already tried myself, but to show you I have edited. Please do check. No changes. I am using Firefox, not Google Chrome as recommended.